# Django 1.6.5 user registration error no such table: auth_user

Tags: django, authentication

my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'crispy_forms',
'Mysite'
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Mysite.PortalUserAbstract'
```

my Mysite.models.py:

```
class PortalUserAbstract(AbstractUser):
is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

error message :

OperationalError at /accounts/signup/client/
no such table: auth_user
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/client/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: auth_user

when i do manage.py syncdb it creates table "Mysite_portaluserabstract" but the auth module still looks for auth_user table.

what am I missing?

Comment: The full traceback should show you the code that is trying to read from the `auth_user` table. Note that Django 1.6.5 is years out of date and missing security fixes.

Comment: Don't use Django 1.6.x, there isn't even documentation online anymore. Use at least 1.11 (the latest long-term version).

Answer (score 0):

You're using Django 1.6, which is very out-of-date - it pre-dates migrations, which will create the missing tables for you. You should upgrade to at least Django 1.11 as was mentioned in comments; if this is a new project, I would recommend using Django 2.1 as of this writing, as the new URL syntax is much friendlier for getting started. It seems to be a new project as you are just starting with a custom user model.

In short:

- Create a new virtualenv
- `pip install django`
- `django-admin startproject myproject && cd myproject`
- `python manage.py startapp mysite`
- edit `mysite/models.py` and add the following:

`class PortalUserAbstract(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

- edit `myproject/settings.py` and add:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Mysite.PortalUserAbstract'`

- run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- run `python manage.py migrate`

Then you should be off and running with the latest version of Django. It would probably do you well to go through the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Good luck!